# Which Apple Developer program Should I enroll to create Passbook passes

Tags: app-store-connect, developer-program, wallet

I am reading this documentation:
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/PassKit_PG/Chapters/YourFirst.html

In order to register a pass type identifier, I need to be an Apple developer.
My pass will be available on a web page (not an iOS app).

Which of the developer programs should I enroll to: iOS/Mac/Safari?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to enroll in the iOS developer program since Pass Type Identifiers are not available to Mac developers and no identifiers are available to Safari developers.

Comment: Thanks! While I am waiting to get approved, I am still wondering how come it doesn't say this on any documentation :)

Comment: @Galz I don't know. When you get approved, file a bug report about that. Generally Apple responds. Not fast, I had a bug I opened last year and got fixed last week.